# What does "move something onto the likes of the couch" mean?

Tags: meaning

I have come across it in the third episode of the tenth season of *Friends*. Here is the [scene](https://youtu.be/OKiD-dIMHzA). It's at around 14 seconds.

> Joey: Yeah.
>
> (Joey and Rachel start kissing)
>
> Joey: Hey what do you say, we **move this onto the likes of the couch**?
>
> Rachel: I say ‘cheesy line’, but ok.

It's clear that Joey wants to kiss on the couch, but I am puzzled by *the likes of the couch*.

Answer (score 1):

**Like** (noun) = "something that is similar" -> (i) **the like of X** = something that is similar to X / (ii) **and/or the like** = and/or something that is similar to a thing or things that have been already mentioned.

2012   Guardian 17 Aug. 34/5   *Happily, we are no longer permitted to discriminate against gender, sexuality, race, religion, disability and the like.*

In the plural, "the likes", it has the same meaning but is informal/colloquial.

In your context, it is a suggestion to move to the couch:

*Hey what do you say, we move this onto the likes of the couch? = Hey what do you say, we move to the couch?*

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Could you clearify one thing? So, he means let's move to something similar to the couch, right?

Comment: Let's move to the couch or something similar.

Comment: ... which would make it easier to become horizontal. Also primetime US TV is pretty puritanical, and I wonder if a joke about 'something similar' to a couch is an acceptable way of suggesting 'bed'.